# ObjectAlreadyConsumedException: Receiving map already consumed

Tags: java, android, react-native

**tl; dr** 
I try to get data of a WritableMap, in the same class and two times. I get `Receiving map already consumed` error and I couldn't overcome that issue.

---

I've been developing a Native Module to use in my React-Native app.

I have 2 classes. One of them is `MyModule` class (is in MyModule.java file) and the other one is a `Worker` class (is in Worker.java file).

In addition `Worker` class has another class its inside that is called `Work` class. Work class offers two methods to do works and to get works status.

`Worker` class has a hash table called as `mWorks`. Worker class checks the incoming `workName` whether the work is already present or not in its constructor method. If the incoming work is already present, the work is assigned to public `work` variable.

When I try to call getState() and doWork() in my App (MyModule) I get the following error;

```
E/unknown:React( 5578): Exception in native call from JS
E/unknown:React( 5578): com.facebook.react.bridge.ObjectAlreadyConsumedException: Receiving map already consumed
E/unknown:React( 5578):         at com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeMap.putNativeMap(Native Method)
E/unknown:React( 5578):         at com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeMap.putMap(WritableNativeMap.java:44)
```

**I guess**, when I call `getState()` method the map data field is consumed. Then if I call `doWork()` I get the error. Because I call `mWorker.work.getState()` in both of `getState()` and `doWork()`.

***Is there any chance to overcome this exception?***

MyModule class have two methods as named getState() and doWork().

```
public class MyModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    ...
    private Worker mWorker = null;
    ...
    public void getStatus(final String workName, final Callback successCallback) {
        mWorker = new Worker(workName);

        WritableMap response = new WritableNativeMap();
        response.putMap("workState", mWorker.work.getState());

        successCallback.invoke(response);
    }

    public void doWork(final String workName, final Callback successCallback) {
        mWorker = new Worker(workName);

        if(mWorker.work.doWork()) {
            successCallback.invoke(response);
            response.putMap("workState", mWorker.work.getState());
        } else {
            response.putMap("workState", mWorker.work.getState());
            response.putString("message", "An error has been occurred.");
            errorCallback.invoke(response);
        }

    }
}
```

Worker class has another class which is called Work.

```
public class Worker {
    ...
    public Work work;
    private Hashtable<String, Work> mWorks = new Hashtable<String, Work>();
    ...
    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public Worker () {
        Work work = null;

        if (this.mWorks.containsKey(pWorkName)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Found an existing Work");
            work = this.mWorks.get(pWorkName);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating a new Work");
            work = new Work(pWorkName);
            this.mWorks.put(pWorkName, work);
        }
        this.work = work;
    }
    ...
    public class Work {
        ...
        public WritableMap getState()  {
            WritableMap result = new WritableNativeMap();

            if (this.isCompleted()) {
                result.putBoolean("Done", true);
            } else {
                result.putBoolean("Done", false);
            }

            return result;
        }

        public boolean doWork()  {
            // do something
            return aBoolValue;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was `response.putMap("workState", mWorker.work.getState());` line which is at the immediate after `successCallback.invoke`!

It had to before the callback invoke.

Comment: what is difference between put and push. I saw most of example has push

Comment: @CrackerKSR , putMap is actually a method of React-Native `WritableNativeMap` 
 class. See: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/WritableNativeMap.java#L42