# Error: Map already consumed - React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Basically I am connecting native android module with react native and passing information from native to js.

```
try {
    WritableMap params = new WritableNativeMap();
    params.putInt("connectionStatus", 2);
    sendEvent(mreactContext, "bleConnectionStatus", params);
    promise.resolve(params);
} catch (Exception exe) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Exception--: " + exe);
    promise.reject(exe);
}
```

It is showing exception

```
Exception--: com.facebook.react.bridge.ObjectAlreadyConsumedException: Map already consumed
```

Note : I have already gone through this answer [ObjectAlreadyConsumedException: Receiving map already consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187058/objectalreadyconsumedexception-receiving-map-already-consumed) but it seems it was about ordering a line. I have written code in that order only still shows exception.

---

**Update**

Exception is in `promise.resolve(params);`, because when I remove this line and run it, it doesn't show any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
WritableArray mylist = Arguments.createArray();
try {
WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
params.putInt("connectionStatus", 2);
sendEvent(mreactContext, "bleConnectionStatus", params);
mylist.pushMap(params);
promise.resolve(mylist);
} catch (Exception exe) {
Log.d(TAG, "Exception--: " + exe);
promise.reject(exe);
}
```

Comment: promise datatype?

Comment: It is `com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise`

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is an old thread but since I just came across this issue when implmenting an Event via an Android to React Native bridge, I thought I'd share the actual problem and solution, in case it's useful to anyone.

The React Native WritableMap is not actually implemented as a Map (at least in the Android domain), it's implemented as a Stream of a Map (or at least it behaves as a Stream). Once it has been consumed (passed, referenced, read etc.), it's no longer available. Think of it as having been Disposed. Unfortunately, this is not immediately obvious in the "extensive" React Native documentation - thanks Meta/Facebook/whatever they are calling themselves this year.

The solution is to use WritableMap.copy() in any uses before the last one (after which you shouldn’t care that it is no longer available).

So the OP's code should be:

```
WritableMap params = new WritableNativeMap();
params.putInt("connectionStatus", 2);
sendEvent(mreactContext, "bleConnectionStatus", params.copy());
promise.resolve(params);
```